# vim freezes for a second when I type % sign in <%

Tags: vim

I have some erb code:

```
... some code
<%= yield %>
```

When I try to type `<%=` in line next to `yield` one, vim freezes for a second before outputing `%`, the same with `=`. When I try it line above `yield` it outputs all characters without any delay.

I'm not sure, but it looks like it's working this way only in this file.

Any idea what's wrong?

My .vimrc file:

```
set nocompatible               " be iMproved
filetype off                   " required!

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plugin 'flazz/vim-colorschemes'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line

" basic settings
syntax enable
set hidden                      " hide buffer instead of closing it
set number                      " line numbers
set laststatus=2                " display the status line always
set cursorline                  " highlight the line of the cursor

" Whitespace
set nowrap                      " don't wrap lines
set tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2      " a tab is two spaces (or set this to 4)
set expandtab                   " use spaces, not tabs (optional)
set backspace=indent,eol,start  " backspace through everything in insert mode
" set list                        " display unprintable characters with '^' and put $ after the line
set scrolloff=3                 " have some context around the current line always on screen

" Searching
set hlsearch                    " highlight matches
set incsearch                   " incremental searching
set ignorecase                  " searches are case insensitive...
set smartcase                   " ... unless they contain at least one capital letterset nocompatible

set noswapfile
set clipboard=unnamedplus       " alias unnamed register to the + register, which is the X Window clipboard
:nnoremap <CR> :nohlsearch<cr>  " clear the search buffer when hitting return

set t_Co=256
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized

"http://askubuntu.com/questions/392573/how-do-i-get-vim-to-indent-all-html-tags
let g:html_indent_inctags = "html,body,head,tbody"
```

Comment: Do you have any insert maps (`imap`, `inoremap`) set that start with a `%`?

Comment: No, I pasted my .vimrc file.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/876049/vim-freezes-for-a-second-when-i-type-sign-in; please don't post simultaneous to multiple StackExchange sites!

Comment: Ok, will remove from superuser, as I think it's more accurate place for this question.

Comment: Could be caused by the syntax highlighting. Try turning that off and see if it fixes it.

Comment: Yes, when I turn off syntax highlighting it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I added `set re=1` to my `.vimrc` and it works much better now.